# Summing specific levels of a factor variable in R

Tags: data-analysis

I have two factor variables, one for smoking and one for sport -
Smoking status: 1 (not), 2 (occasional) and 3 (regular, i.e. more than once per week)
Sport participation: 1 (not regular) and 2 (regular).

smoking_status <- data_1995$smoke

smoke <- factor(smoking_status, levels = c(1, 2, 3), labels = c("not", "occasional", "regular"),
ordered = TRUE)

sport_participation <- data_1995$sport

sport <- factor(sport_participation, levels = c(1, 2), labels = c("not regular", "regular"),
ordered = TRUE)

I want to get the proportion of people that smoke at least occasionally, and the proportion that regularly practiced sport and smoke at least occasionally. Any advice about how to access these specific levels would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!